# How to make my robot use an URL response time

Tags: java, delay, awtrobot

I'm a java beginner and I'm trying to program a robot that will fill a very annoying form for me.

Why is this form annoyin? Imagine I have to insert a thousand different values into this form but it only lets me insert one value at a time. Everytime time I insert each value I have to press an "OK" button and wait for the URL to update (this takes from 1 to 50s) and only so I'm able to insert another one.

To solve the problem I made a robot that uses a 1min delay between each "OK", but this is far from optimal, since when the URL updates in 1s the robot stays useless for a minute. Even worst, if the url takes more than 1min to update my robot is going to fill the form wrongly.

Is there anything I can do to detect when the url has updated and then use this information as the delay to my robot?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you using java to insert values into a webpage?

Comment: My program gets the values that I want to insert from an excel document and then it copies each value to clipboard and pastes then using the robot's "mouse press" and "mouse release" functions.

Comment: I'm just using control v, tab and enter

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is

```
    Robot.getPixelColor(x,y)
```

which returns the color of a pixel on the screen. You can tell the robot to wait until the pixel is colored "correctly" (which would happen when the page is completely loaded).

Comment: Nice idea, i'm gonna go ahead and try it! xD

Comment: You can't be sure that there isn't any JavaScript that isn't changing the pixel or something. Also, what happens if the same pixel goes through 3 different colors (your solution works if there are only 2 colors at the same pixel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium. It provides a good API and lots of tools for you to automate browser work. Some people might argue that this is not the purpose of the library, but I think that in your case it should work. Link: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Why I think this is the solution:

> Selenium is a suite of tools specifically for automating web browsers.

Which seems to be just what you are requesting.

P.S. There are third party drivers as well. For instance, you can download a driver for the Chrome browser.